# Getting sensor data in an IntentService and receiving using a broadcast

Tags: java, android, accelerometer, android-sensors

I am developing an application to set system alarms automatically by judging the movement and environment of a mobile phone using accelerometer and light sensor data.For doing this, I have am using IntentService + Alarm Manager . I want my service to get the sensor data and broadcast it. I capture the broadcast in another activity and write the sensor values to a file. I use alarm manager so that I can get the sensor values periodically. I'm facing two problems :

1. I'm not able to capture sensor data in my service.
2. Receive data from the service and write it to a file.

As I can see on my Logcat, only 'onCreate' and 'onHandleIntent' methods of my intentservice are being executed. The 'onSensorChanged' method is not being executed. Is it because I'm sending a broadcast in the 'onHandle' method and the service doesn't execute anything else other than that. If this is so, please guide me as to how can I achieve my use case of getting sensor data in a service and sending it back to activity to perform further processing at regular intervals.
Following is my code :

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{
         @Override
            protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
                scheduleAlarm();
            }

            // Setup a recurring alarm every 15 minutes
            public void scheduleAlarm() {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Scheduling Alarm.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                // Construct an intent that will execute the AlarmReceiver
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AlarmReceiver.class);
                // Create a PendingIntent to be triggered when the alarm goes off
                final PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, AlarmReceiver.REQUEST_CODE,
                        intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
                // Setup periodic alarm every 5 seconds
                long firstMillis = System.currentTimeMillis(); // alarm is set right away
                AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager) this.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
                // First parameter is the type: ELAPSED_REALTIME, ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, RTC_WAKEUP
                // Interval can be INTERVAL_FIFTEEN_MINUTES, INTERVAL_HALF_HOUR, INTERVAL_HOUR, INTERVAL_DAY
                alarm.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, firstMillis,
                        AlarmManager.INTERVAL_FIFTEEN_MINUTES, pIntent);
            }
```

AlarmReceiver.java

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    public static final int REQUEST_CODE = 12345;
    public static final String ACTION = "com.example.tyagi.smartalarm.alarm";

    // Triggered by the Alarm periodically (starts the service to run task)
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.d("AlarmReceiver", "Alarm called.");
        Intent i = new Intent(context, sensorService.class);
        i.putExtra("foo", "bar");
        context.startService(i);
    }

}
```

IntentService.java

```
public class sensorService extends IntentService implements SensorEventListener {

    public static final String ACTION = "com.example.tyagi.smartalarm.sensorService";
    private SensorManager sensorManager;    // this instance of SensorManager class will be used to get a reference to the sensor service.
    private Sensor mSensor,lSensor;         // this instance of Sensor class is used to get the sensor we want to use.
    private float[] mGravity;
    private float mAccel;
    private float mAccelCurrent;
    private float mAccelLast;


    TextView xCoor; // declare X axis object
    TextView yCoor; // declare Y axis object
    TextView zCoor; // declare Z axis object
    TextView lightVal;
    // constructor for the java class. Mandatory, otherwise was showing error.
    public sensorService() {
        super("sensorService");
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate(); // if you override onCreate(), make sure to call super().
        // If a Context object is needed, call getApplicationContext() here.
        Log.d("sensorService","onCreate");
        sensorManager=(SensorManager) getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);          // get an instance of the SensorManager class, lets us access sensors.
        mSensor = sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);    // get Accelerometer sensor from the list of sensors.
        lSensor = sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_LIGHT);            // get light sensor from the list of sensors.
        mAccel = 0.00f;
        mAccelCurrent = SensorManager.GRAVITY_EARTH;
        mAccelLast = SensorManager.GRAVITY_EARTH;
    }

    public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor,int accuracy){


    }

//    // if sensor value is changes, change the values in the respective textview.
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event){
        Log.d("sensorService", "onSensorChanged.");
        /* check sensor type */
        if(event.sensor.getType()==Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER){

            mGravity = event.values.clone();
            // assign directions
            float x=event.values[0];
            float y=event.values[1];
            float z=event.values[2];
            xCoor.setText("X: "+x);
            yCoor.setText("Y: "+y);
            zCoor.setText("Z: "+z);

            float x1=event.values[0];
            float y1=event.values[1];
            float z1=event.values[2];
            mAccelLast = mAccelCurrent;
            mAccelCurrent = (float)Math.sqrt(x*x + y*y + z*z);      // we calculate the length of the event because these values are independent of the co-ordinate system.
            float delta = mAccelCurrent - mAccelLast;
            mAccel = mAccel*0.9f + delta;
            if(mAccel > .5)
            {
                Toast.makeText(sensorService.this, "Movement Detected.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
        else if(event.sensor.getType()==Sensor.TYPE_LIGHT)
        {
            float l = event.values[0];
            lightVal.setText(l+"");
        }

        /* unregister if we just want one result. */
        sensorManager.unregisterListener(this);

    }


    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        // This describes what will happen when service is triggered

        // Fetch data passed into the intent on start
        String val = intent.getStringExtra("foo");

        // Construct an Intent tying it to the ACTION (arbitrary event namespace)
        Intent in = new Intent(ACTION);
        in.putExtra("resultCode", Activity.RESULT_OK);
        in.putExtra("resultValue","My result value. Passed in : " + val);

        // Fire the broadcast with intent packaged
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(in);
        // or sendBroadcast(in) for a normal broadcast;
        Log.d("sensorService", "Service running");
    }
}
```

RegularService : as suggested by @Mike I tried using a regular service. This time also, only the onCreate method of this is getting executed. Rest nothing happens.

```
public class MyService extends Service implements SensorEventListener{
    public MyService() {
    }

    private SensorManager sensorManager;    // this instance of SensorManager class will be used to get a reference to the sensor service.
    private Sensor mSensor,lSensor;         // this instance of Sensor class is used to get the sensor we want to use.
    private float[] mGravity;
    private float mAccel;
    private float mAccelCurrent;
    private float mAccelLast;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate(); // if you override onCreate(), make sure to call super().
        // If a Context object is needed, call getApplicationContext() here.
        Log.d("MyService", "onCreate");
        sensorManager=(SensorManager) getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);          // get an instance of the SensorManager class, lets us access sensors.
        mSensor = sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);    // get Accelerometer sensor from the list of sensors.
        lSensor = sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_LIGHT);            // get light sensor from the list of sensors.
        mAccel = 0.00f;
        mAccelCurrent = SensorManager.GRAVITY_EARTH;
        mAccelLast = SensorManager.GRAVITY_EARTH;

    }

    public int onStartCommand(){
        Log.d("MyService","onStartCommand");
        return START_STICKY;
    }
    public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor,int accuracy){


    }

    //    // if sensor value is changes, change the values in the respective textview.
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event){
        Log.d("sensorService", "onSensorChanged.");
        Toast.makeText(MyService.this, "onSensorChanged.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        /* check sensor type */
        if(event.sensor.getType()==Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER){

            mGravity = event.values.clone();
            // assign directions
            float x=event.values[0];
            float y=event.values[1];
            float z=event.values[2];

            float x1=event.values[0];
            float y1=event.values[1];
            float z1=event.values[2];
            mAccelLast = mAccelCurrent;
            mAccelCurrent = (float)Math.sqrt(x*x + y*y + z*z);      // we calculate the length of the event because these values are independent of the co-ordinate system.
            float delta = mAccelCurrent - mAccelLast;
            mAccel = mAccel*0.9f + delta;
            if(mAccel > 3)
            {
                Toast.makeText(MyService.this, "Movement Detected.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
        else if(event.sensor.getType()==Sensor.TYPE_LIGHT)
        {
            float l = event.values[0];
        }

        /* unregister if we just want one result. */
//        sensorManager.unregisterListener(this);

    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        // TODO: Return the communication channel to the service.
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not yet implemented");
    }
}
```

Comment: `IntentService`s stop themselves pretty much right after the `onHandleIntent()` method ends, so your `sensorService` doesn't get a chance to receive any sensor info. You're going to need a regular `Service`.

Comment: Ohk. But can I implement normal service with a Broadcast and alarm manager ? My main concern is to run the service to get the sensor data periodically( like every 15 minutes). Since Intent Service stop themselves after the first call, my first of thought of using them was to save battery so that a service is not always running in the background.

Comment: "But can I implement normal service with a Broadcast and alarm manager ?" - Sure. Your `Service` need only run long enough to get a sensor callback, then it can stop itself.

Comment: hey, I tried using a normal service. Still, the 'onSensorChanged' method inside my service is not getting called. I have updated the question with the code for regular service.

Comment: Oops. I didn't notice before, but you never register your Sensors. You need to call `SensorManager#registerListener()` for each. I don't think it matters, though, because I don't believe your IntentService would live long enough to receive a Sensor callback. You might try it, though.

Comment: Hi, thanks for sparing your time for me. I register listeners in the 'onCreate' method of both Intent Service and Regular service. still there was no action. 
I have also tried registering the sensor listeners in onStartCommand() method (as I'm calling my service using startService() function ). But still nothing happened. I'm really getting confused now

Comment: let me update my query here : I want to create a service, that collects accelerometer data in background and write the data to a file. Right now I'm able to call the service from my activity but once the service gets started, nothing happens